# simple adder + testbench returning "dont care" input

Tags: verilog, iverilog

i have a simple test bench for an adder module, but I am getting the wrong input:

```
module adderTestbench;

    wire [31:0] fromAdd;

    adder lol(32'h00000000,fromAdd);


    initial begin //forcing program to be sequential
    #100; //wait 100
    end //end begin

    initial begin
    $display("%h",fromAdd);
    end

endmodule

module adder(addIn,addOut);
input [31:0] addIn;
output reg [0:31] addOut;
always @(addIn) 
begin
addOut <= addIn + 32'h00000004;
end
endmodule
```

It displays `xxxxxxxx`.

Can anyone explain why it is not displaying 4, instead it's displaying x's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code marked as  *"//forcing program to be sequential"* does not make any code sequential.
Your two initial statements will still run in parallel. You probably mean:

```
initial
begin
   #100; //wait 100
   $display("%h",fromAdd);
end
```

Comment: this helped for sure, but just let me know if I'm understanding correctly: what makes your code sequential is the fact that the #100 is inside the inital statement. Since the code in my OP has #100 outside of it, verilog will just run both the code with #100 and the display at the same time, essentially doing nothing that I want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Knowing that you need a delay is what 99% of the Verilog beginners have a problem with. So you outperformed  those! Just the way the delay was set was wrong. All initial statements are executed simultaneous in parallel.